# Resolve using not found in visual studio 2012 right click menu.How to add it?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: visual studio 2008 right click menu]

This image from visual studio 2008,But this menu not contain in visual studio 2012.**How to enable this resolve menu in visual studio 2012. ?**

Anyway any other solution to add Assembly references with out that menu option are acceptable to me.any one know about that?

Answer (score 0):

The `Resolve` item will only appear in the context menu when you right-click on a resolvable type.

Selecting an item from the `Resolve` sub-menu will **not** add assembly references for you. In fact, a reference to the assembly defining the type you wish to resolve must already be added for the resolve menu to appear. All the `Resolve` command will do for you is to insert the appropriate `using` statement or fully qualified type name.

So, the most likely reason the resolve menu does not appear is that VS does not know how to resolve the name you clicked on, as it is not the name of a type in any of the assemblies currently referenced by your project.

Another reason for VS not recognizing that the name you clicked on is a resolvable type is if it is also the name of a namespace that is within current scope. This one has had me scratching my head for a bit in the past.